# How can I set the height of the classic editor per post-type?

Tags: custom-post-types, tinymce

Can't seem to find any valuable info on this at the moment - I just want to resize the height of the classic editor field for my Custom Post types.

I was hoping to just drop a function or code snippet into functions.php for this, if possible?

In this example I would have 3 Custom Post types: 'Tools', 'Brand' and 'Company' and for all three I would like the editor to only be about a qtr of its height or about 120px tall or 8 lines.

Many thanks for any help in on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to adjust the TinyMCE [settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12382735/2078474):

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', function( $settings ) {
    $settings['height'] = '120';
    $settings['autoresize_max_height'] = '120';
    return $settings;   
} );
```

and e.g. restrict further on post types and !block editor with [get_current_screen()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/).

Example:

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', function( $settings ) {

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( $screen->is_block_editor() ) {
        return $settings;
    }        

    if ( ! in_array( $screen->post_type, ['tools', 'brand', 'company'], true ) ) {
        return $settings;
    }        

    $settings['height'] = '120';
    $settings['autoresize_max_height'] = '120';

    return $settings;
 } );
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am so new to PHP the get current screen is a bit over my head, would you mind editing your answer to include this for post types: 'Tools', 'Brand' and 'Company' ? I did paste your code into functions.php with no success. (I am building a custom-theme)

Comment: Works on my install with Classic Editor. Try e.g. `$screen = get_current_screen();` and then wrap settings with `if ( ! $screen->is_block_editor() && in_array( $screen->post_type, ['tools', 'brand', 'company'], true ) ) { ...settings here ... }`. Note that body class is also inside `$settings['body_class']`.

Comment: I tried but its now throwing `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen() `
Here it is on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BKiuh2H5) I probably don't have something correct yet. ~ Appreciate your help!

Comment: it goes into the function, not outside it, and no endif;

Comment: I tried multiple ways to make this work, and keep getting errors - sorry (still a noob) I guess I just need someone to just write the whole thing out for me please: [codepen-collab](https://codepen.io/shrockco/pen/MWmOVmb)
Thanks!

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Very grateful - Thanks a million!

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert custom style in the WP admin section via `admin_head` action hook.

```
function wp123_set_editor_height() {
  ?>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* For PAGE post type */
    body.post-type-page #postdivrich #wp-content-editor-container iframe {
      height:  120px !important;
    }
  </style>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wp123_set_editor_height' );
```

Say for example your custom post type is "sample" then you have to target the body as follows:

`body.post-type-sample`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, so I pasted that into my functions.php following your instructions, but nothing worked?